# Backbone Create - Success not called

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

I am currently trying to add to a collection (a mysql DB on the back end). This behavior works however once the model is created success is never called (see below). Here is my save function on the front end.

```
save: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var that = this;
        var postCollection  = this.postCollection;

        var newPost = {
            message:$('#message').val(),
            author_id:"22",
            location:$('#location option:selected').val(),
            base64encode:$('#upload-photo').data('base64'),
            filename:$('#upload-photo').data('name')
        }

        this.postCollection.create(
            newPost,
            {
                wait: true,
                success: function(response){
                    Util.setPageType('open-main');
                    that.router.navigate("stream", {trigger: true});
                },
                error:function(err) {
                    console.log("this is the error "+ err.toJSON);
                }
            });

        return this;
     }
```

On the backend I am inserting into a mysql DB and returning the newly created object. I am using a custom in house CMS (written in php) but essentially all I am doing is inserting and this behavior works fine. I'm just curious what I should be returning from the backend if not the object?

Comment: You might want to add the code that receives and responds to the creation of the `NewPost` so we can see it. Unless you modified some of the default Backbone behavior, you will need to return the saved object rendered as a JSON object.

Comment: Are you returning HTTP status code 200? Can you see the response in the browsers network monitor? Are you returning an id for the newly created object?